# Restart the computer when the power on time exceeds 30 minutes

Tags: linux, bash, uptime

I was currently controlling this through an uptime.
The computer restarts if uptime is greater than 1h.

But I do not know how to control if the computer is one day on or more, because currently I only control the hours.

Is it possible to control days, hours and minutes with uptime?
I need to restart the computer when the power on time is greater than 1h.
If the time is 1 day and 0 hours gives failure.

Sorry for my explanation, it is a script that does a series of things and alfinal exists this function that is responsible for controlling this parameter.

thanks for reading me

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming, but about Linux usage. I suggest to re-ask this question on https://unix.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I quite understand your issue.

If you want your computer to ALWAYS reboot after a specific amount of time, which is very unusual, then use cron. Add this to `/etc/crontab` (alternatively, if there is a `/etc/cron.d` directory on your machine, you can also create a file `/etc/cron.d/reboot` with this content) :

```
@reboot    root    sleep 1800; /sbin/reboot
```

(adapt `reboot`'s path to match your system; `1800` is the number of seconds for 30 minutes, change it to whatever delay you need)

---

On the other hand, you may be writing a script that will reboot your server, and you may want to keep it from working if it is run before 30 minutes of uptime (which makes more sense).

Then, I understand you have difficulties parsing the result of `uptime` and you should use `/proc/uptime` which gives your uptime in seconds:

```
#!/bin/sh
not_before=1800             # Number of seconds - adapt to your needs
uptime=$(cut -d . -f 1 /proc/uptime)

[ "$uptime" -ge "$not_before" ] && exec reboot
echo "Sorry, only $uptime s of uptime; you must wait $((not_before - uptime)) seconds" >&2
exit 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in a script, use the result of `uptime | grep "` day"`to determine whether to execute things (in an`if`condition), then do anything you want inside the`if`.

Make that script executable and put it in crontab to run every 5min or so.

More information on Cron: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Cron

Comment: Sorry for my explanation, it is a script that does a series of things and alfinal exists this function that is responsible for controlling this parameter.

Comment: No worries @RubenSerenaTellechea, could you please edit your question? I updated my answer with a solution to the comment :)

Comment: AFAIK `60 * * * *` is not a valid cron entry. Minutes must be 0 to 59. Moreover, if your server as rebooted at 12h45, your cron will trigger a reboot 15 minutes later, i.e. it's not going to wait 60 minutes.

Comment: @xhienne oh, so it would run only at that minute in the crontab :(, you're right, my first solution wouldn't work, I'll update it to remove that first part